# How to get one content loadable DIV to scroll and another to remain viewable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML setup below.  The right column will have variable amount of content, but the left column will have additional loadable content as one scrolls to the bottom of the page.  My question is how to get the right column to remain viewable as the left column is scrollable, without seeing scroll bars in the left column.

The left column will always have more content than the right column.

```
 #wrap{
    width: 1000px;
}
.col{
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

}
#leftC{
    height: 2000px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;

}
#rightC{
    height: 500px;

}
#head{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#div2{
    width: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

</style>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="head">Header</div>

    <div class="col" id="leftC">LEFT COLUMN</div>
    <div id="div2">
        <div class="col" id="rightC">RIGHT COLUMN</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**HTML**

```
  <div id="scrollable">Your scrollable text</div>
  <div id="notScrollableContainer" class="boundariesNotScrollable">
  <div id="notScrollable" class="boundariesNotScrollable">
    Your scrollable text
    <div id="fixedElement"> Your fixed text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="scrollable">Your scrollable text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fixedPosition{
  position: fixed !important;
}
.relativePosition{
  position: relative !important;
}
#scrollable{
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}
#notScrollableContainer{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.boundariesNotScrollable{
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100%;
}
#notScrollable{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 2px;
}
#fixedElement{
  background: yellow;
}
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var ns = $("#notScrollable");
ns.addClass("relativePosition");
var fixedHeight = $("#fixedElement").offset().top;
var nscHeight = $("#notScrollableContainer").offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > fixedHeight) {
    ns.removeClass("relativePosition");
    ns.addClass("fixedPosition");
    var offset = (nscHeight-fixedHeight);
    $("#notScrollableContainer").css("margin-top", offset+"px");
  }else{
    ns.removeClass("fixedPosition");
    ns.addClass("relativePosition");
    $("#notScrollableContainer").css("margin-top", "5px");
  }
});
});
```

Comment: thanks but thats not what I am after. this detaches the right column from the header

Comment: If you set the position as fixed, then all the positioning values (top, left, right, bottom) will be relative the top left corner of the screen. So adjust the values

Comment: I'm trying to get the effect like Facebook, where the right column is scrollable and then becomes fixed as it reaches the end of its content, but the left column is still scrollable, however the content on the right column is still viewable. .do you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes now I understood

Comment: Do you have a non-jQUERY solution?  plain javascript would be great.

Comment: No, JQuery is quieten and it hasn't contraindications

Answer (score 0):

Howz that ?

```
<style>#wrap{
width: 1000px;
}
.col{
width: 400px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;

}
#leftC{
height: 2000px;
margin-right: 20px;
float: left;

}
#rightC{
height: 500px;

}
#head{
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
background: #ccc;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#div2{
width: 450px;
overflow: hidden;
float: right;
position: relative;
}

#new_div2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

</style>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="head">Header</div>

    <div class="col" id="leftC">LEFT COLUMN
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>


    </div>
    <div id="new_div2">
        <div class="col" id="rightC">RIGHT COLUMN <br>R data<br>R data<br>R data<br>R data<br>R data</div>
    </div>
</div>
```